# Call to undefined method Application_Model_DbTable_Projects::lastInsertId()

Tags: zend-framework

I want to retrieve the id of the last inserted row. This is the code I use in the mapper:

```
public function save(Application_Model_Projects $project)
{
    $data = array(
        'id_user' => $project->getIdUser(),
        'project_name' => $project->getProjectName(),
        'project_description' => $project->getProjectDescription(),
        'due_date' => $project->getDueDate(),
        'id_customer' => $project->getIdCustomer()
        );
    if(($id = $project->getId()) === null) {
        unset($data['id']);
        $this->getDbTable()->insert($data);
        return $this->getDbTable()->lastInsertId();
    }else {
        $this->getDbTable()->update($data, array('id = ?', (int) $id));
        return $id;
    }
}
```

According to the code above, it should return the `id` of the object. It is either the `id` after insertion or the current `id`.

The code where I use this function:

```
$currentUser = new Application_Model_UserAuth();
$project = new Application_Model_Projects();
$project->setProjectName($formValues['projectName'])
        ->setProjectDescription($formValues['projectDescription'])
        ->setDueDate(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($formValues['dueDate'])))
        ->setIdCustomer($formValues['assignCustomer'])
        ->setIdUser($currentUser->id);
$projectMapper = new Application_Model_ProjectsMapper();
$idProject = $projectMapper->save($project);
```

The error I get is:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method Application_Model_DbTable_Projects::lastInsertId()`

What is wrong with this? Shouldn't that return the last id? Because it is triggered upon insertion. In another sequence of code I call the `lastInsertId`: `$Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->lastInsertId()`. The only difference is that now I call `lastInsertIt` on a dbTable, that extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question above is that I should call `getAdapter()` before `lastInsertId()`.

Updated code:

```
if(($id = $project->getId()) === null) {
    unset($data['id']);
    $this->getDbTable()->insert($data);
    return $this->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an single-column Primary Key the return value is lastInsertId by default, so you also can use this:

```
return $this->getDbTable()->insert($data);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this works or not as my table has composite primary keys.

Comment: Guess maybe it a cleaner solution, but when you have multiple primary-keys it return an array so not the thing you want.